# representation from a ideal to $B(H)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

[image]
I am reading Conway's book, A Course in Operator Theory. I don't understand the definition of representation $\rho$ here. In the start of this section, he only defined the representation from a $C^*$-algebra to $B(H)$. But in 6.10 Proposition, the ideal isn't required to be closed, thus it may be not a $C^*$-algebra, then we don't know the representation means what?

So, i want to ask if the ideal in Proposition should be added a condition "closed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. Any bounded operator on a subspace can be uniquely extended (as a bounded operator) to the closure of the subspace. If said bounded operator is a $*$-homomorphism, so is the extension. That $*$-homomorphisms are bounded was shown earlier in the book (Proposition 1.7).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer！And I want to ask the other question: In the proof of this proposition, it claim that ideal $I$ has an approximate identity, but I only know that closed ideal of $C^*$-algebra has an approximate identity. I want to ask that is there an approximate identity in general ideal ?

Comment: The proof doesn't use the order properties of the approximate unit. So you can take an approximate unit for the closure of I, and then take elements in I that are progressively closer to the approximate unit. Also, please upvote if you found the answer useful.

Comment: OK, I got it. thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :)